# Woocommerce Shop Page Product Display Bug

Tags: wordpress

When I go to my shop page products are displayed in a very strange way : Product details take lot of place. I tried to understand what have changed since yesterday and I notice (inspecting element via Chrome) that the html code before was :

```
<ul id=product ....>
   <li class=product_item ...>
     <div class=image container>...</div>
     <div class=clearfix>...</div>
     <div class=product details>...</div>
   </il>
</ul>
```

and now I have this following code (and it destroy my product list display) :

```
 <ul id=product ....>
   <div class=t_singleproduct_cont>
    <li class=product_item ...>
        <div class=image container>...</div>
    </il>
   </div>
   <div class=clearfix>...</div>
   <div class=product details>...</div>
 </ul>
```

As you can see the product details is outside the li tag and so my shop page is such a mess.

I tried to identify where this piece of code was coming from and I found that it was inside the content-product.php file but I can't see the line with "t_singleproduct_cont" div.

If you could help to deal with this problem I'll be very grateful !

Thank you very much

Comment: You should search your entire theme directory for `t_singleproduct_cont`

Answer (score 0):

@Tayfun Akaltun. Have you installed plugin called enhanced e-commerce plugin for google analytics?

Comment: @Tayfun. A newer version of Enhanced Ecommerce plugin (1.0.12) has released which resolves your issue.

Just update the plugin from your back end to see the Enhanced Ecommerce data in your GA.